# Two Django Projects with One Database

Tags: django

I built a dashboard with Django that all my customers use. I want to build an **internal dashboard** for myself so that I can monitor their activity. It should **connect to the same database** as the dashboard. I have a a question about how to do this:

Do I just **add the same database** in `settings.py` and **re-define the models** in the internal dashboard?

Thanks! If there's a better way to do this, let me know!

Comment: There are several options to do this. Connecting to the same database and replicating everything is possible but far from optimal. You could also use the same codebase for both and use the Django Sites system to split the websites. Or you can make a separate app for your internal dashboard which you install on both sites. Or you can import one (or both?) applications from your internal dashboard application to avoid replication.

Comment: Why not add an extra app to the same django project? The concept of apps is entirely to define multiple entites in the same project.

Comment: @Wolph I see, would the best option here be to use Django Sites? Is it possible to change the domain here as well? Or have to separate load balancers? Thanks!

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem When adding the extra app, would I just use Django Sites as Wolph mentioned? I want them to be at different endpoints.

Comment: The Django Sites system mostly assumes that you have a single codebase that's used for multiple websites. Which means the same apps, the same database, the same url structure. But you can definitely have separate domain names per site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Multiple Django projects can share single database. There is no harm in that. Only thing to keep in mind that, only one of the projects should run migrations for the sake of simplicity.

You can generate the `models.py` file for your internal application by running the following command from your original application

```sh
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

This allows you to generate a Django models file from an existing database. By default `inspectdb` generates models with `Model.Meta.managed = False` i.e. this particular application where generated model is going to be used, is not responsible for creation, deletion or update of the database table. In case of generated models you might need to configure the relationships since, `inspectdb` generates all relationships as `ForeignKey` and generates `through` tables to maintain relationships. You might also need to provide `related_names` based on your requirements.

In summary, you can use the same databse(s) across multiple django projects. More in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/legacy-databases/)

Comment: Thanks so much for this answer! Is this way better or better to use Django Sites as recommended above?

Comment: `django-sites` framework assumes that you have same code base for two different domains. In your case, you want to use the admin site as an internal tool(I assumed admin is not accessible from public network, where sites framework you have to do extra work to prevent requests from public network to your admin sit)   , the above mentioned approach of sharing database seems more appropriate.

Comment: I see, just to confirm, I will have to run the `inspectdb` command anytime my models change in my main dashboard?

Comment: No. Even running `inspectdb` once isn’t mandatory You can just straight away copy paste your models and set `managed = False`. But `inspectdb` will be useful when you do not have access to the original models or you are integrating your project with a legacy database.

Comment: Ok this makes sense. Btw, what does `legacy database` mean?

Comment: legacy database means a database that is already existing in action

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much!! Btw, do you have experience with AWS roles in Django?

Comment: unfortunately, no experience for with AWS IAM roles. Did some work on GCP IAM

Comment: No worries! Wait, I thought I understood, but I am confused again ;). So, if I make a change to my database via my dashboard (for example, renaming a field), then wouldn't I  need to run `inspectdb` once again on my internal dashboard to ensure that the models are up to date? Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: In case of renaming, just rename in both files. `inspectdb` is helpful for the generating django models for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

#simply run this code in terminal and write app name in which you want to access database tables

python manage.py inspectdb > your_app_name/models.py